# Different behaviors in stringstream given std::hex, uint8_t vs int

Tags: c++, stringstream, cstdint

I suppose the fact that `std::uint8_t` is really just an alias for char means that when the characters in the stringstream get read back in, they are stored natively, i.e. the ascii code for the character, whereas if the char is input to an int, with `std::hex` specified, it gets read in as a hex digit converted to base 10.

This is a small example exhibiting the behavior, but the reason I'm asking is because I started out under the assumption that specifying an output vector of `std::uint8_t` was the right approach, as I need to later feed this vector as an array to a C function as a byte vector (you pass it in as a void pointer and it figures out what do to with it somehow).  So I figured reading in pairs of input chars into a string stream and then out into a `std::uint8_t` would help me skip manually bitshifting.  Is there a way of keeping the idea of reading into a `std::uint8_t` but invoking the handling of an `int`?  Can I cast to `int` at the point of the read from the stringstream?  Or what?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
  uint8_t n = 0;
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << 'F';
  ss >> std::hex >> n;
  std::cout << "uint8:" << (int)n << std::endl;

  int m = 0;
  std::stringstream tt;
  tt << 'F';
  tt >> std::hex >> m;
  std::cout << "int:" <<  std::hex << m << std::endl;
  
  return 0;
}
```

output

```
uint8:70
int:f
```

Comment: Since `uint8_t` is usually just a synonym for `unsigned char`, the `>>` operator reads it as a character.  You'll find that 70 is the ASCII value of `'F'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [`operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) overloads for `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char`, which all read a single character from the stream. A `uint8_t` argument selects the `unsigned char` overload as the best match, reading `F` as a character (ASCII code 70 or 0x46).

To match an integer extraction [`operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) overload, use an argument of type `short` or bigger (for example, `uint16_t`):

```
  std::uint16_t n = 0;
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << 'F';
  ss >> std::hex >> n;
```

> *Can I cast to int at the point of the read from the stringstream?*

No. The argument is taken by reference, which in function calls works as a pointer. Type punning a `uint8_t` argument as `(int&)` will invoke undefined behavior. Just use a bigger type instead.

Comment: The salient point being not that a bigger type is necessary, just a different type from uint8_t?

Comment: You could say a different type, yes, but not int8_t or bool (that works differently).